# Relationship matrix-pointer

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I was wondering why in C this is possible:

```
    int MATRICE[20][20];
int *p; p = MATRICE[19]; is equal to p = &(MATRICE[19][0]);
```

I tried to interpretate it in this way: I consider the label "MATRICE" as a constant pointer and like an array of pointers, so when it comes to the 20th pointer (MATRICE[19]) it points at the same thing that MATRICE[19][0] points too.
Is my idea correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

This expression

```
MATRICE[19]
```

yields a one-dimensional array of the type `int[20]` that is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int *` when used as an initializer (as a right side hand expression in the assignment) in this code snippet

```
int *p; p = MATRICE[19];
```